# Update Customer table from selected Ids and assign one of three distinct values to each

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, sql-update, common-table-expression

I have a fairly complex query which results in a list of Customer Ids where they have not ordered within a defined period, have no Rep assigned to them, and are business customers rather than private. This simply returns a sequential list of Ids which match the BIGINT primary keys of the matching customers, like this:

```
CustomerId
13
17
51
76
87
97
123
131
285
315
381
433
464
466
536
539
549
604
681
729
792
etc.
```

I now want to update the records with those Ids and assign to each a RepId from one of three Sales Reps:

```
RepName RepId
Fred    25
Doris   50
Sybil   99
```

My problem is to assign the rep Ids. Actually doing it is easy, as per this pseudocode:

```
UPDATE Customers SET RepId = [CalculatedRepId] WHERE CustomerId IN (QueryResult)
```

The problem is calculating the relevant Id. I have considered a number of approaches including selecting RowNumber() and using the number and its relation to three to select the number, and incrementing a variable and using that to assign the relevant Id, but I cannot get it to work. I also considered splitting the results into three and assigning separately but again cannot work out how to do it and in any case that is definitely not an ideal approach - for a start with imported ordered data that would skew the results giving each rep customers in a range depending on entry order.

The desired result would be something like this:

```
CustomerId RepId
13         25
17         50
51         99
76         25
87         50
97         99
123        25
131        50
etc.
```

The order of the RepIds is not necessarily critical, but shown as I originally envisaged it the idea being to share the customers between the Reps as evenly as possible.

**EDIT - the final solution**

I was able to apply the list of Ids by simply adding a WHERE clause to the cte_customers proposed by @forpas:

```
WITH 
  Reps AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (1), (3), (12)) v(RepId)), -- your RepIds
  cte_reps AS (SELECT RepId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RepId) - 1 rn, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt FROM Reps),
  cte_customers AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId) - 1 rn FROM Customers WHERE Customers.CustomerId IN 
  (
        SELECT CustomerId FROM Customers WHERE Inactive = 0 AND TotalBlock = 0 AND RepId < 1 AND TypeId > 0 AND TypeId <> 10 
        AND NOT Exists (SELECT CustomerId FROM @TransIds t WHERE t.CustomerId = Customers.CustomerId))
  )
UPDATE c
SET c.RepId = r.RepId
FROM cte_customers c INNER JOIN cte_reps r
ON r.rn = c.rn % r.cnt;
```

That worked perfectly!!

Comment: Is there a table with the RepIds?

Comment: As in my other comment, there is a table with the Rep Ids in it, but these are only a few of the Rep Ids. I need to assign available Reps to available customers identified by the CustomerIds. Therefore we would need to exclude the unwanted reps somehow...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is a table `Reps` with the `RepId`s that you want to use to update the table `Customers`, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to join the tables in the `UPDATE` statement:

```
WITH 
  cte_reps AS (SELECT RepId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RepId) - 1 rn, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt FROM Reps),
  cte_customers AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId) - 1 rn FROM Customers)
UPDATE c
SET c.RepId = r.RepId
FROM cte_customers c INNER JOIN cte_reps r
ON r.rn = c.rn % r.cnt;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Vyfo0-F4).

If you want to supply only specific `RepId`s use an additional CTE:

```
WITH 
  reps AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (25), (50), (99)) v(RepId)), -- your RepIds
  cte_reps AS (SELECT RepId, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RepId) - 1 rn, COUNT(*) OVER () cnt FROM Reps),
  cte_customers AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CustomerId) - 1 rn FROM Customers)
UPDATE c
SET c.RepId = r.RepId
FROM cte_customers c INNER JOIN cte_reps r
ON r.rn = c.rn % r.cnt;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/PA1ucV7X).

Comment: Whilst there is a table with the Rep Ids, not all of the reps are to be included. We have x specific sales reps vs y available customers to assign. I can easily put the Ids in a table variable if we need just those ones.

Comment: @oldcoder check my 2n query.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it would work for my current requirement, I will test ASAP. I was hoping for something simpler and compatible with other databases like VistaDB and SqlLite which I do not believe support OVER, so if you have any suggestions there they would be appreciated. If not, hopefully I have the answer I need to solve the initial problem.

Comment: @oldcoder SQLite supports window functions since version 3.25.0 (2018)

Comment: @oldcoder but this query will not work in SQLite because its syntax for joins in the UPDATE statement is different.

Comment: Yes, I know. It won't work in VistaDB either... That is not necessarily an issue. What is an issue is that I need to update a table with around 15k customers and only those that match the specification should be updated. These are the values returned by the complex query I mentioned in my original question. I cannot see in your query were we are picking up the query results - am I being stupid again?

Comment: @oldcoder in my 2n query I provide the RepIds with the first cte: `reps AS (SELECT * FROM (VALUES (25), (50), (99)) v(RepId))`. You can replace it with your query: `reps AS (<your code here>)`

Comment: I am sorry if I have been unclear. I am talking about customers not Reps. In the question I state that I have a set of Customer Ids that are returned by a complex query and a sample of that data is listed as part of the question. I need to update only the customers represented by those Customer Ids which are returned by the complex query, leaving the other 12k or so customers untouched as they will either have reps or reps are not appropriate.

Comment: @oldcoder check this:https://dbfiddle.uk/Dpb46u9p

Comment: Thanks @forpas, I had arrived at the same solution myself and added the where clause shown in the final solution edit. Really grateful for your advice.